# Error 3090003 - How to provide signatures for eosio.code?

Tags: nodeos, eosjs

When I try call custom smart contract action I get this error.

> message":"transaction declares authority:
>
> '{\"**actor\":\"triviafrenzy\",\"permission\":\"active**\"}', but does
>   not have signatures for it under a provided delay of 0 ms, provided
>   permissions
>
> [{\"**actor\":\"triviafrenzy\",\"permission\":\"eosio.code**\"}],
>   provided keys [], and a delay max limit of 3888000000 ms

---

Full error:

```
{
   "code":500,
   "message":"Internal Service Error",
   "error":{
      "code":3090003,
      "name":"unsatisfied_authorization",
      "what":"Provided keys, permissions, and delays do not satisfy declared authorizations",
      "details":[
         {
            "message":"transaction declares authority '{\"actor\":\"triviafrenzy\",\"permission\":\"active\"}', but does not have signatures for it under a provided delay of 0 ms, provided permissions [{\"actor\":\"triviafrenzy\",\"permission\":\"eosio.code\"}], provided keys [], and a delay max limit of 3888000000 ms",
            "file":"authorization_manager.cpp",
            "line_number":517,
            "method":"check_authorization"
         },
         {
            "message":"pending console output: ",
            "file":"apply_context.cpp",
            "line_number":72,
            "method":"exec_one"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

How can I provide signatures ?

Comment: Please delete the comment and officially answer the question then accept your own answer.  This helps the stack exchange by improving the percentage of answered questions and it will also give you additional experience.